# How to retry IndexError in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

Sometimes I get IndexError because I successfully scrape only half of the page causing the parsing logic to get IndexError. How can I retry when I get IndexError?

It's ideally a middleware so it can handle multiple spiders at once.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I use a decorator and call `_retry()` function from `RetryMiddleware` in the decorator function. It works well. It's not the best, it's best to be able to have a middleware handling it. But it's better than nothing.

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware

def handle_exceptions(function):
    def parse_wrapper(spider, response):
        try:
            for result in function(spider, response):
                yield result
        except IndexError as e:
            logging.log(logging.ERROR, "Debug HTML parsing error: %s" % (unicode(response.body, 'utf-8')))
            RM = RetryMiddleware(spider.settings)
            yield RM._retry(response.request, e, spider)
    return parse_wrapper
```

Then I use the decorator like this:

```
@handle_exceptions
def parse(self, response):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that page needs to be reloaded if error is encountered you can try:

```
max_retries = 5

def parse(self, response):
    # to avoid getting stuck in a loop only retry x times
    retry_count = response.meta.get('retry_count', 0)

    item = {}
    try:
        item['foo'] = response.xpath()[123]
        ...
    except IndexError as e:
        if retry_count == max_retries:
            print(f'max retries reached for {response.url}: {e}')
            return
        yield Request(
            response.url, 
            dont_filter=True, 
            meta={'retry_count': retry_count+1}
        )
```

Comment: In the end, it's impossible to solve it using a middleware. I mean, one middleware to handle multiple spiders